# bash. break file into lines and then break by first equal sign. handle unescaped characters

Tags: bash

I have an environment file that I normally use to set environment variables, but we are switching gears a bit and now want to use that env file to create multiple files from it.

My env file has lines that look like this:

```
MAIL_SETTINGS={"service": "service", "auth": { "user": "example.com", "pass": "pass=something"}}
```

I want to spit each line by the first equal sign and have two variables.
`MAIL_SETTINGS` and `{"service": "service", "auth": { "user": "example.com", "pass": "pass=something"}}`

I've tried a few things, but keep coming up empty.

```
for line in $(cat .env | grep -v ^#); do
  start=$(echo "$line" |cut -d"=" -f1)
  end=$(echo "$line" |cut -d"=" -f2)
  echo "$start = $end"
done
```

A couple issues.

- If there are multiple equal signs, it seems to break on each of them
- Unescaped characters like `{` just separates into multiple lines.

How do handle the special characters and only split on first equal sign?

Thanks!

Comment: From the posted code, it looks like you want to add spaces around `=` signs. And you say you want to create multiple files, but you did not describe what to put in each file.

Comment: No, I don't need to add spaces. I was just debugging.
I want to create a file where the filename is $start (before the equal sign) and the contents is $end (after first equal sign).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for line in $(cat .env | grep -v ^#)` will split each line in the input on spaces, so it's not going to work at all.
You need to read lines using a `while` loop with `read`.

Don't use `cut` to split the line.
You can extract the left and right parts of the first `=` sign using *parameter expansion*:

- Get the name by chopping off everything after the first `=`
- Get the value by chopping off everything until the first `=`

Like this:

```
while read -r line; do
  name=${line%%=*}
  value=${line#*=}
  echo "$value" > "$name"
done < <(grep -v '^#' .env)
```

Comment: Ah. Thanks. I had tried pattern expansion, but using the `for line` and maybe was using one `%`, so it was all wrong. Thanks so much!  Why do you use a space between the `<`? So it's like `< <` and not `<<(grep...`

Comment: @SenicaGonzalez If you write `<<(...)` it will mean something else, and not work.

Comment: found a post https://askubuntu.com/questions/678915/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-bash Thanks again!